# iOS 8 UITextView scroll-to-caret issue after inserting newline character

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, autolayout, uitextview

The automatic scroll-to-caret behavior of an iOS 8 `UITextView` is better than that of an iOS 7 `UITextView`. However, I'm still seeing an issue in the scroll-to-caret behavior when the text view's text contains a newline character (`\n`).

Here's the issue described in screenshots:

[image]

ABOVE: `UITextView`'s default Latin text is displayed. Notice that I inserted a newline character after the word `laborum`. The text was set in code.

[image]

ABOVE: The user clicks in the space after the last word, `civiuda`, the keyboard pops up, and the text view automatically scrolls to the caret. This is expected.

[image]

ABOVE: The user taps the return button on the keyboard and the caret is lost behind the keyboard. This is an unexpected issue.

If I remove the newline character from the text view's text, the issue disappears. Moreover, if I move the newline character closer to the beginning of the text (e.g., after the first word, `Lorem`), the issue also disappears.

Am I doing something wrong? If not, can anyone offer a fix?

The `UITextView` is instantiated in IB using Autolayout.

[image]

**Here's the code:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // text contains a newline character after the word 'laborum'; removing the newline character eliminates the scrolling issue
    self.textView.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\nNam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.";

    self.textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:26];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    CGRect keyboardRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    keyboardRect = [self.textView convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil];

    UIEdgeInsets insets = self.textView.contentInset;
    insets.bottom = keyboardRect.size.height;
    self.textView.contentInset = insets;
    self.textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets;

    // doesn't fix the scrolling issue
    [self.textView setNeedsLayout];
}
```

**What I have tried:**

Instead of using the `UITextView'`s `contentInset`, I tried using a bottom constraint to push the text content above the keyboard. Same scrolling issue.

I instantiated the `UITextView` in code. Same scrolling issue.

It was suggested that tapping the return key may be misinterpreted as the done-editing key by the system. I went ahead and registered for the keyboard hide notifications. They're not being called.

Comment: It's probably just broken on iOS 8. There were several attempts to fix text view since iOS 7 (https://github.com/steipete/PSPDFTextView) but turns out situation didn't get much better.

Comment: Could you post the code you use to move the scrollview back down? Because it sounds like your view is scrolling down as if the keyboard's resigning when you hit enter...as if it's mistaking "return" as an end to the user's editing.

Comment: @LyndseyScott The code is already posted at the very bottom of my post. Note that a second tap of the return key re-establishes normal scroll-to-caret behavior.

Comment: @bilobatum That code is only executed when the keyboard appears. I'm talking about the code that should execute when the keyboard *dis*appears.

Comment: @LyndseyScott Ok, I tested your theory. The hide keyboard notifications aren't being called when I hit enter. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#param mark - UITextViewDelegate

- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (IOS8) {
        [self.textView scrollRangeToVisible:self.textView.selectedRange];
    }
}
```